# How to sort .net Arraylist containing ListItems, by Value

Tags: .net, sorting, arraylist

```
 Dim alCustomers as New ArrayList

 Dim li1 As New ListItem("John", 7)
 alCustomers.Add(li1)

 Dim li2 As New ListItem("Abe", 2)
 alCustomers.Add(li2)
```

How can I sort the alCustomers arraylist, by Value?

Abe,2

John,7

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Hi, using .net 2.0 unfortunately, the answers look great though but the OrderBy function was not in .net 2.0. Hope there is a way around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# with .NET 3.5 or newer it would work like this:

```
// Create a list of ListItem objects
List<ListItem> alCustomers = new List<ListItem>();

// Add the list items
alCustomers.Add(new ListItem("John", 7));
alCustomers.Add(new ListItem("Abe", 2));

var orderedCustomers = alCustomers
    // Order the items by their value...
    .OrderBy(item => item.Value)
    // and convert it to a list.
    .ToList();
```

Unfortunately since the last version of Visual Basic I used was VB6, I am not sure how to translate that. This is my best guess:

```
// Create a list of ListItem objects
Dim alCustomers as New List(Of ListItem)

// Add the list items
alCustomers.Add(New ListItem("John", 7))
alCustomers.Add(New ListItem("Abe", 2))

Dim orderedCustomers As List(Of ListItem) = alCustomers
    // Order the items by their value...
    .OrderBy(Function(item As ListItem) item.Value)
    // and convert it to a list.
    .ToList(Of ListItem)()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq:

```
alCustomers = alCustomers.OrderBy(Function(item) item.Value)
```

This solution requires a `List` instead of an `ArrayList`.